# Discord Bot Using Reactions on Embed Message Discord .Net

Tags: c#, discord, embed, discord.net

I'm having some trouble with my Discord bot not being about to add reactions to the embed message Its Sending Any Ideas below is the code I have so far

```
   [Command("raid")]
        public async Task DisplayPic(string raid, string date)
        {        
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
            string day = dateTime.ToString("ddd");

             if (raid == "GoS" && day == "Fri")
            {
               // Emote emote = ":thumbsup:";
                var filename = "Garden_of_Salvation_Friday.png";

                var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                {
                    Title = "Garden of Salvation",
                    Description = "Must be Level 1230",
                    ImageUrl = $"attachment://{filename}"
                                
                }.Build();

                var myReaction = new Emoji("");

                await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(filename, embed: embed);
                await Context.Message.AddReactionAsync(myReaction);
               
               
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform actions on a message which is sent by the bot, you need to assign the message to a variable like so.

```cs
IUserMessage sentMessage = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(...);
```

In your case you want to add a reaction, so you can use the AddReactionAsync method in the same way that you used it on Context.Message in the code you provided.

```cs
await sentMessage.AddReactionAsync(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case this should work.

```
var msg =  await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(filename, embed: embed);
msg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji(""));
```